# Cast variable parameter list to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, casting

I got a function with a variable parameter list. Depending on the type specifier, all other parameters have a different meaning. In the concrete case, all parameters, except the first, contain byte arrays. I want to cast them to a two dimensional byte array:

```
function foo(byte type,Object ...parameters) {
   ...
   switch(type) {
      case 1: short ID=(short) parameters[0];
              byte[][] payloads=(byte[][]) Arrays.copyOfRange(parameters,1,parameters.length); //exception here
              ...
   }
   ...
}
```

The caller calls the function with

```
byte[] byteArray1=...;
byte[] byteArray2=...;
...
foo((byte)1,byteArray1,byteArray2,...);
```

The code looks logical and compiles, but theres an ClassCastException "Object cannot be cast to [[B" thrown as soon as I execute the code.

How to get all parameters, except the first one, as two dimensional byte array?

Comment: No comments but a negative rating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not cast array types. `short[]` can not be cast to `byte[]`, etc.

However, I think you could use generics to solve your problem:

```
public <T> void foo(T[] ... params) {
    Class<?> clazz = params[0].getClass();
    if (clazz.equals(short[].class)) {
        //...
    } else if ( ... ) {
        //...
    } else {
        throw new Exception("expected short[] or int[]");
    }
}
```

You can't put `clazz` into switch, but if-else if-else sequence will be just a bit slower.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no soulution, as the parameters do not all contain the same type. As described in my question the first parameter contains a short, while the remaining contain byte arrays.

Comment: if that's the case, why not simply `foo(short[] p1, byte[] ... pn)`? Your question is not clear.

Comment: "Depending on the type specifier, all other parameters have a different meaning.", isn't this clear enough? Even the first field may not always contain a short.